# Perfomance and SSE code

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, x86, sse

I have problems with performance of my SSE code. I try to calculate Pi number and I use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80 . So, when I do 1*10^11 iterations I have worse performance (-100%), than code without SSE. If I do 1*10^10 iterations I have better performance than code without SSE.

I use Visual Studio C++ compiler and Intel Compiler (Without optimization!). Of course I can use compilers with optimization (and I'll get perfect results), but I want to understand what's wrong.

I tried to align data (You can see it) and I got better performance with VS C++ compiler (-40% instead of -100%), but performance with Intel Compiler I got -85% instead of -100 :) 
I use getTickCount to measure time.

My processor is AMD Turon X2 Dual-Core Mobile-RM74. May be it makes sense :)

My code with SSE

```
    double *a = (double*) _mm_malloc(4 * sizeof(double  ), 16);
double *i = (double*) _mm_malloc(sizeof(double), 64); //good point
double *k = (double*) _mm_malloc(sizeof(double), 64);
double *result = (double*) _mm_malloc(sizeof(double), 64);
double *temp = (double*) _mm_malloc(sizeof(double), 64);
*temp = 0.0;
*result = 0.0;
*k = 1.0;
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = -1;
for (*i = 1; *i < 100000000000; *i += 2, *k += 4.0) {
        a[2] = *k;
        a[3] = *k + 2;
    __asm {
        mov eax, dword ptr a

        movapd XMM0, xmmword ptr [eax ]
        movapd XMM1, xmmword ptr [eax + 16]

        divpd XMM0, XMM1

        movapd XMM1, XMM0

        psrldq XMM1,8

        addpd   XMM0,XMM1  
        mov eax, dword ptr temp;

        movsd [eax], XMM0
    }

    *result += *temp;
}

*result = *result * 4.0;
```

**Timing** getTickcount. ms.

```
intel + O       | 942901
intel - O       | 1273139
intel + sse + O | 948096 
intel + sse - O | 2354382 |(unaligned data)
VS + O          | 949079
VS - O          | 1106749
VS + SSE + O    | 968189
VS + SSE - O    | 2180067 | (unaligned data)
VS + SSE - O    | 1674201 | (aligned data)
intel + sse - O | 1921437 |(aligned data)
```

Comment: Have you considered using compiler intrinsics ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4atda1f2(v=vs.80).aspx ) instead of pure assembler?

Comment: *when I do 1*10^-11 iterations* [That is not a lot of iterations](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1*10%5E-11&x=0&y=0).

Comment: I've thought about it but not so interesting :) But, may be I will use it.

Comment: When compiling  without optimizations, you should have *no* expectations on the runtime performance. None!

Comment: OF course 1*10^11! I made mistake in text =(

Comment: Could you please rephrase the execution timings. (a table is typically quite readable)

Comment: The table is still missing the dependency with iteration count, which I thought was the relevant part of the question. If and when it's not, the results simply mean that optimizing just a few instructions is often counterproductive, as compilers are often much better at that. Manual optimizing can be productive, when the calculation is transformed into a form, that can not be represented by c language or is outside the techniques known by optimizing compiler.

Comment: I was going to help, but then I read `double *i = (double*) _mm_malloc(sizeof(double), 64); for (*i = 1; *i < 100000000000; *i += 2 … )`. That is not cool. Floating-point variables do not make good integer indexes, even if it works. Please fix it. And use intrinsics while you're at it.

Comment: Are you trying to get the worst possible performance or you just don't understand how computers work? Why are you using indirect pointers for all of your variables? As someone mentioned, using a pointer to a DOUBLE as an integer counter is absurdly bad. The rest of the loop should be kept in CPU registers. An optimizing compiler might see through the obvious mistakes in your code and output decent code, but when optimization is disabled it will create what you asked for - a loop that runs many times slower than it needs to.